# Using Bitly API to shorten URLs

Tags: php, url, url-shortener

I found the Bitly API code below on [this](http://ditio.net/2010/08/15/using-bit-ly-php-api/) site.  I'm having a hard time getting it to create and then echo a Bitly shortened URL for a variable called $fullurl.  How would I do that?

**EDIT:** No error code appears, just no bitly shortened URL is shown.

**EDIT 2:** `var_dump($response);` returns NULL

**EDIT 3:** I did replace the API login and key with my mine.

**EDIT 4:** I found the answer in one of the comments on the original tutorial.  My question was too basic for all you PHP pros: I simply needed to add `echo bitly_shorten($fullurl);` at the end.

Thanks in advance,

John

```
function bitly_shorten($url)
{
    $query = array(
        "version" => "2.0.1",
        "longUrl" => $url,
        "login" => API_LOGIN, // replace with your login
        "apiKey" => API_KEY // replace with your api key
    );

    $query = http_build_query($query);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.bit.ly/shorten?".$query);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $response = json_decode($response);

    if($response->errorCode == 0 && $response->statusCode == "OK") {
        return $response->results->{$url}->shortUrl;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: For debugging purposes, you should echo the `$response->errorCode` and `$response->statusCode`.  That should give you a clue as to what went wrong.

Comment: `var_dump($response)` for debugging

Comment: Did you replaced the login and api key with your login and key ???

Comment: Yes, I'm using my API login an key.

Comment: Thanks, this code worked perfectly with Edit 4 included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in one of the comments on the original tutorial.  My question was too basic for all you PHP pros: I simply needed to add `echo bitly_shorten($fullurl);` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
function bitly_shorten($url){
  $query = array(
    "version" => "2.0.1",
    "longUrl" => $url,
    "login" => API_LOGIN, // replace with your login
    "apiKey" => API_KEY // replace with your api key
  );

  $query = http_build_query($query);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?".$query);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  $response = json_decode($response);
  if( $response->status_txt == "OK") {        
    return $response->data->url;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bit.ly had updated their api , please visit

http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#Authentication_and_Shared_Parameters

for api..

The url seems to be something like this, **`http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?.....`**

The new version they stated is 3 and in your code its 2.0.1

**Whenever you are using an api of an online service its better to get it from their site instead of getting that from any third party site or blog..**

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, and I should probably use that.  But it works with the old Bitly URL.

Comment: :) simple mistake, that why you should post exactly all of which you have done and not a part code.. If you would have done that, you could have got this answer from SO much earlier .. :)